# C#. WinForms DataGridView. Заполнить колонку типа DataGridViewComboBoxColumn

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Добрый день, есть список типов List Users;

```
public enum Role {Наблюдатель, Администратор, Диктор, Инженер }    
public class User : EntityBase
{
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public Role Role { get; set; }
}
```

Необходимо отобразить этот список в DataGridView (WinForms),
В редакторе создаю DataGridView с тремя колонками типа 
(DataGridViewTextBoxColumn, DataGridViewTextBoxColumn, DataGridViewComboBoxColumn).
Последняя колонка типа ComboBox должна быть заполнена Role (Наблюдатель, Администратор, Диктор, Инженер).

DataGridView должна быть с возможностью добавления новой строки.

Я для теста попытался заполнять по частям (сначала для ComboBox потом для TextBox):

```
    var column = dgv_пользователи.Columns[2] as ataGridViewComboBoxColumn;
    if (column != null)
    {
        column.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Role));
    }

   foreach (var user in Users)
   {
    this.dgv_пользователи.Rows.Add(new object[] { "col1", "col2"  });
   }
```

Значения попадают куда надо но вылазит исключение ComboBox при редактировании.

Подскажите как ПРАВИЛЬНО заполнить такой грид?

Comment: Имя свойства **Role** совпадает с объявленным *enum*, это нормально?

Comment: Да конечно имя произвольного типа может быть именем св-ва

Answer (score 0):

```
dgv_пользователи.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
dgv_пользователи.DataSource = Users;

var Logincol = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
{
    DataPropertyName = "Login",
    HeaderText = "Login",
    Name = "Login",
};
var Passwordcol = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
{
    DataPropertyName = "Password",
    HeaderText = "Password",
    Name = "Password",
};

dgv_пользователи.Columns.Add(Logincol);
dgv_пользователи.Columns.Add(Passwordcol);

DataGridViewComboBoxColumn Rolecol = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();

Rolecol.HeaderText = "Role";
Rolecol.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Role));
Rolecol.DataPropertyName = "Role";
Rolecol.ValueMember = "Role";
Rolecol.DisplayMember = "Role";

dgv_пользователи.Columns.Add(Rolecol);
```

Answer (score 0):

Получилось вот так

```
private void FillTable(IEnumerable<User> users )
{
    //Очистить грид.
    dgv_пользователи.Rows.Clear();

    //Заполнить ComboBox вариантами выбора.
    var column = dgv_пользователи.Columns[2] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn;
    if (column != null)
    {
        column.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Role)).Cast<Role>().Where(r=> (r != Role.Администратор) && (r != Role.Наблюдатель)).Select(r => r.ToString()).ToArray();
        column.DataPropertyName = "Role";
    }

    //Заполнить грид.
    for (int i= 0; i < Users.Count; i++)
    {
        var user = Users[i];

        dgv_пользователи.Rows.Add();
        dgv_пользователи["clLogin", i].Value = user.Login;
        dgv_пользователи["clPassword", i].Value = user.Password;

        DataGridViewComboBoxCell cell = dgv_пользователи["clRole", i] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell;
        if (cell != null)
        {
            cell.Value = user.Role.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Считывание после редактирования

```
    for (int i = 0; i < dgv_пользователи.Rows.Count - 1; ++i)
    {
        var login = (string)dgv_пользователи["clLogin", i].Value;
        var password = (string)dgv_пользователи["clPassword", i].Value;
        var role = (string)dgv_пользователи["clRole", i].Value;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(login) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(login))
        {
            MessageBox.Show($@"Задайте верно логин в строке: {i+1}");
            return;
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(password) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password))
        {
            MessageBox.Show($@"Задайте верно Пароль в строке: {i + 1}");
            return;
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(role) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(role))
        {
            MessageBox.Show($@"Задайте верно Роль в строке: {i + 1}");
            return;
        }

        Users.Add(new User { Login = login, Password = password, Role = (Role)Enum.Parse(typeof(Role), role) });
    }
```